# Replace new lines with "\n" when read from URL

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email and the body of the email is a "GET" text from URL. This text is basically an email text that is in the format as given below:

```
Hi,

Nice to meet you.

Best regards.
```

However when copied to a URL it looks like this:

```
https://localhost/GetEmail.php?myBody=Hi,

Nice to meet you.

Best regards
```

I am not writing this body text, I am receiving it from a text file and this is the format I receive it in.
And in my GetEmail.php script I am trying to add new line so ultimately it looks like a body email.

```
<?php
$myBody = htmlspecialchars($_GET['myBody']);
$bodyFinal = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', preg_replace('/\s*$^\s*/m', "\n", $myBody));
..
..
?>
```

But unfortunately the final text looks like

```
Hi,Nice to meet you.Best regards
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `the body of the email is a "GET" text from URL`...consider using a POST instead of a GET, it's more appropriate for this kind of data. Then you won't have to worry about the lines.

Comment: If you used GET, newlines wouldn't be your only issue. You'd still have to account for spaces. If you absolutely had to use GET, encode your message with base 64, although I'm not sure what the url size limit would be. But as everyone has already suggested, POST is your better option.

Comment: Hey guys thank you for your replies. I infact used POST, but now when I run the URL to receive the myBody text, I get an error ```Undefined index: myBody....```

Comment: I am not sure what actual problem you are trying to solve here? If the parameter gets passed to the script like this, then the value you receive should contain newlines already.

Comment: The undefined index is probably because you did not modify `$_GET['myBody']` accordingly?

Comment: @CBroe I did it this way ```$myBody = htmlspecialchars($_POST['myBody']);```. Is this the right way?

Comment: If that gives you `Undefined index: myBody`, then you did not properly send a POST parameter by the name `myBody` to begin with.

Comment: `when I run the URL`...what do you mean by "run the URL" exactly? Just putting the URL into your browser's search bar will always generate a GET, for example. You need to send a POST somehow, but it's unclear what is going on in reality - are you using another PHP script to read from the text file and generate the HTTP request or something like that?

Comment: Ah I get it now. The text is readable from an external program and that generates the URL. So I need to use POST from there. Alternatively, a user said I can do it with GET but using base 64. How do I work with this?

Comment: well you could use the base64_encode function potentially, but even that user said you should try using POST first. So yes amend the external program which generates the GET URL, so that it sends a POST request directly.

Comment: Thanks alot I shall test it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of GET use POST:

```
$myBody = htmlspecialchars($_POST['myBody']);
```

With post you doesnt send your data through the URL you use the HTTP-Request its recommended for bigger data/information

Answer (score 0):

In email body there is no `\n` to be rendered. You can use the function `nl2br()` to convert all `\n` to html `<br>` tags and display it.

Comment: You're assuming it's a HTML email, there's no guarantee of that. Plain-text email also exists.